# Can Exchange 2010 Re-Route Outbound Messages Based On X-Header?

Tags: email, exchange, smtp, exchange-2010

I'd like to know if it's possible to configure Exchange 2010 to read x-headers from an outbound message (say, user@internaldomain.com to user@yahoo.com) and then re-direct the message to an alternate smarthost if the x-header is present. Does anyone know if this can be done?

Comment: in exchange 2003 if I recall this was possible by scripting an outbound filter and applying it via the admin console, I used to have this occur to apply legal disclaimers for all outbound mail. I can't say for sure with EX2010 as I do not have a deploy to experiment upon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can not be done out of the box. 
However it can be done with several third party extensions or you can write a custom transport agent if you have .net experience.

[Sample Code::How to control routing from your own routing agent](http://blogs.technet.com/b/appssrv/archive/2009/08/26/how-to-control-routing-from-your-own-routing-agent.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

No - at least not as you're describing it.

In ESM, look at your `Organization Configuration | Hub Transport | Transport Rules`. One of the Conditions you can configure is *when the message header contains specific words*. If you look at the Actions step of the wizard, you can fiddle with the message itself - adding recipients or putting a legal disclaimer in the body. What isn't there is anything that can directly change the message's routing.

There are third-party products that will choose a smarthost based on sender - but a quick search doesn't seem to turn up anything that works on a message header.